# To change the Case tab title to case field name in service cloud

Tags: case, servicecloud

Hi I want to change the CASE tab Title to Case Subject. Subject is a standard case field. The screenshot is given below. Any pointers on this would be really great. Thanks

[image]

Currently, the case title has the value of CaseNumber associated with it. I want to rename that to the Case Subject value below. TIA

Answer (score 1):

You can't change the title on standard Salesforce pages I'm afraid.  You can change this if you go the Visualforce route, via the `<apex:sectionHeader/>` component, but I wouldn't recommend Visualforcing the record view for an object for such a minor change.